# The arguments for and against using an iframe for a single sign-on system

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I am currently assessing what are the best options to integrate multiple sites to a single sign-on system. The ambition is to have a unified header with shared assets across the sites. Currently it operates as a separate login page where the user is redirected back to the page they were on before, similar to Google accounts.

There has been a proposal for an iframe or a popup iframe.

The benefits for this appear to be entirely for the user, so the user does not have to leave the page they are on. My concerns with this approach are

- if we make changes to the login page itself we will need to make changes to the iframe which could require a redeployment of all the sites at the same time
- the suggestion for a regular iframe is intricate to the design and will create problems across browsers
- pop up iframes are problematic on mobile devices
- if a user has scripting disabled they will be unable to login
- a user may have a pop up blocker in place

Does anyone have any other arguments for or against using iframes for an SSO system? Any critique on the points I have already raised are also greatly appreciated.

Thanks!